# Remove parentheses / unprettify SQL view in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, formatting, mysql-workbench, sql-view

MySQL workbench (or perhaps it is MySQL itself) keeps formatting my SQL VIEW every time with so many parentheses that I cannot insert or modify code easily because I need to first untangle the parentheses. Does anyone know of a way to remove these parentheses (without removing legitimate parentheses such as in IFNULL() functions, etc.) or prevent MySQL from "prettifying" these VIEW queries?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Example below:

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(`c`.`id`, 0)
    ....
FROM
    ((((((((`c`
    JOIN `r` ON ((`c`.`id` = `r`.`cid`)))
    JOIN `c` ON ((`c`.`id` = `c`.`csd`)))
    JOIN `b` ON ((`b`.`carton_id` = `c`.`id`)))
    LEFT JOIN `cs` ON ((`cs`.`id` = `b`.`csd`)))
    JOIN `od` ON ((`od`.`id` = `b`.`odid`)))
    JOIN `oh` ON ((`oh`.`id` = `od`.`oid`)))
    JOIN `cm` ON ((`cm`.`id` = `oh`.`cid`)))
    JOIN `i` ON ((`i`.`id` = `od`.`iid`)))
```